# How to stop applications from uninstalling themselves?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, google-chrome

Some applications keep "uninstalling" themselves.

For example, I installed *Google Chrome* via *[Ubuntu After Install](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-after-install)* and it was working great. In the middle of a normal browsing session, I noticed that the Chrome icon in the dock had turned grey. Didn't know what it was, so I closed my Chrome window, and then the icon in my dock disappeared. I searched my applications for Chrome, but curiously it had disappeared. When I opened up *Ubuntu After Install*, it said that Chrome wasn't installed. So I reinstalled it, and it works fine again. But then the problem repeated itself.

This also happened when I downloaded and installed the *Whatever* .deb file (wrapper for Evernote). I downloaded the .deb, installed it via *GDebi*. I was able to find the application when I searched for it, however it would not open, and now has dissapeared from my application search (even though the .deb file is still in the same place).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try installing Google Chrome directly, without using UAI?  Seems like Whatever is broken or incompatible - since it's not Ubuntu software, you should let them know that it's broken.

Comment: I installed Google Chrome directly (via their provided .deb file) and have run into the same issue. Sometimes it 'uninstalls' after less than an hour of use, other times it may last a few days.

Comment: The icon on your "dock" is *supposed* to disappear unless you right-click and tell it to remain permanently. Next time Chrome vanishes, open a terminal, enter the command `which google-chrome` and let us know the complete output.

Comment: Yes I realize that it's supposed to disappear if it's not docked - however it was docked and when it greys out and I close my browser, it disappears (likely because it uninstalls itself). Your command returned nothing (did not find the binary)

Comment: Does anything you install remain installed? Do applications and data persist after, say, a reboot? Does the Chrome .deb file you downloaded vanish from your Downloads (or wherever) directory?

Comment: Some applications remain (such as Spotify and Dropbox that were installed via _UAI_). Once I reinstall Chrome, it maintains my google account logged in. Chrome was installed via _UAI_ so I don't know where the .deb is located, but Whatever's .deb remains in the directory after it "uninstalls itself".